# How can I check element order in xml

Tags: xml

I wrote a little mock-up for an api, and I want to be sure that the generated xml has the same tag order as the real one. I dont want to check the values in the tags, and tags can be missing. I have to check only the order of the existing tags.

E.g:

```
<root data="somedata">
  <sub-element>
     <sub-sub-element />
     <sub-sub-element />
  </sub-element>
</root>
```

is the same as

```
<root data="otherdata">
  <sub-element>
  </sub-element>
</root>
```

but not the same with this

```
<root data="somedata">
  <other-wrapping-element>
     <sub-element>
        <sub-sub-element />
        <sub-sub-element />
     </sub-element>
  <other-wrapping-element>
</root>
```

What is the easiest way to check this? I am looking for some ready to use online tool or program, but any advice for an easy & fast implementation is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the API provides already [XML Schema Definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema) (XSD) for it's messages, you may define them on your own. Then validate against the schema.